# unlink() function don't work without any error

Tags: php, mysql, unlink

i have problem with my code and unlink function

here my code

```
if(isset($_GET['delimg'])){

$id= $_GET['delimg'];
$sql = "delete from images_img where id='$id'";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$getname="select * from images_img";
$res2=mysqli_query($con,$getname);
$image=mysqli_fetch_array($res2);
$image1=$image['image_url'];
$image2=$image['image_url_big'];
unlink('../../images/photo'.$image1);
unlink('../../images/photo'.$image2);

}
```

when i run my `delete.php` in the database the images deleted just fine

but the unlink function don't work and don't delete anything from the path and no error shows !

my thought that the select way return empty value ! as i use

this `$image=mysqli_fetch_array($res2);` to select the images name

so any error with my code please ?

UPDATE ::

i'm sure that the delete excuted before selecting the data for name to delete >>

so how i would arraying the order ?

UPDATE 2 :::

this is the upload code

```
$nameimg=$_FILES['image']['name'];
$tmp=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
$size=$_FILES['image']['size'];
$dir="/images/photo/";
if($_POST['upload']){
if(!empty($nameimg)){
if(in_array($type,array('image/png','image/jpg','image/gif','image/jpeg'))){
if(filesize($tmp) <= 20242880){
move_uploaded_file($tmp,$dir.$nameimg) ;
$done ="done";
}
else {$errorsize= "it's bigger than the allowed size";}
}
else {

$errortype= "the file not image,please choose image to upload";

}
}
if(empty($nameimg)){$errorchoose= "no file choosen,please choose file";}
}
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5;url=../../admin.php#ajax/add_img.php'>";

?>
```

Comment: will you please use this line print_r($image) after fetch_array.This will give you the array of result. I need this to solve the issue.

Comment: i put it like this

    $image=mysqli_fetch_array($res2);
print_r($image); 

but nothing shown

Comment: is the table image_hair have any data ?

Comment: Can you please share the folder structure of the project?

Comment: WordpressCoder yes of caurse .. oh .. i notice something maybe the delete query from the database excuted before the select of value .. right !!

Comment: You use images_img table to delete but fetching the data from the images_hair table.I an unable to understand this.Because if you want to delete the row then first select the data and fetch it and stored in the variable then use delete query

Comment: no no i just missed the images_hair .. it's just the same table [images_img]

Comment: i used this but nothing worked if(unlink('../../images/photo'.$image1) && unlink('../../images/photo'.$image2)){
 $sql = "delete from images_img where id='$id'";
 $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
}

Comment: I am giving the answer which tells you that what is the procedure to delete this image. Then you tell me whats the problem ?

Comment: i update the answer .. my problem simply is 

i have a table "images_img" i want delete the column and the images from the folder where the name equal the name stored in "image_img"

Comment: what should be the image name?

Answer (score 0):

Copy this code and tell me whether it is working or not?

```
 if(isset($_GET['delimg'])){

            $id= $_GET['delimg'];
            $getname="select * from images_img where id='$id'";
            $res2=mysqli_query($con,$getname);
            $image=mysqli_fetch_array($res2);
            $image1=$image['image_url'];
            $image2=$image['image_url_big'];
            $sql = "delete from images_img where id='$id'";
            $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
            unlink('../../images/photo/'.$image1);
            unlink('../../images/photo/'.$image2);

        }
```

Comment: sorry sorry .. it's my fault that it dosen't delete from database >> i missed a charcter in  if(isset($_GET['delimg'])) .. so now it's delete from the database just fine >> but still the function unlink dosen't work .. again a million thanks to you and sorry for i make you check the code because my stupid fault ^_*

Comment: Don't worry for this mistake.Its a human nature.But now you should write the line print_r($image); and tell me whats the output and please use die() function after closing the if statement which is required to check the result

Comment: i tried a lot to print_r($image); but nothing printed  .. i try in php code and in the html code by this <?php print_r($image); ?> .. both ways not working and nothing printed   !

Comment: Will you please replace this $image=mysqli_fetch_array($res2);  with the line -->  $image=mysqli_fetch_array($res2,MYSQLI_ASSOC); and print the $image.

Comment: nothing worked but i use this $image4=print_r($image); and i echo the variable .. and it print this "1" !!

Comment: .. the result"1" given by             $image=mysqli_fetch_array($res2,MYSQLI_ASSOC); so i will try this but with this             $image=mysqli_fetch_array($res2);

Comment: yesh my code is  if(isset($_GET['delimg'])){

            $id= $_GET['delimg'];
            $getname="select * from images_img where id='$id'";
            $res2=mysqli_query($con,$getname);
            $image=mysqli_fetch_array($res2); 
            $image1=$image['image_url'];
            $image2=$image['image_url_big'];
            $sql = "delete from images_img where id='$id'";
            $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
            unlink('../../images/photo'.$image1);
            unlink('../../images/photo'.$image2);

        } so i try create var $image4=print_r($image); and i given "1"

Comment: if(isset($_GET['delimg'])){
    $id= $_GET['delimg']; 
    $getname="select * from images_img where id='$id'"; 
    $res2=mysqli_query($con,$getname); 
    $image=mysqli_fetch_array($res2,MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
    print_r($image);
    echo $image1=$image['image_url']; 
    echo $image2=$image['image_url_big'];
    die;
    $sql = "delete from images_img where id='$id'"; 
    $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
    unlink('../../images/photo'.$image1); 
    unlink('../../images/photo'.$image2); 
   } Please use this code and pardon me that I am taking your so much time to solve this issue.

Comment: hhhh !! you please a million excuse me for taken your time .. 
so yes before your code i get the print_r work here what i given

Comment: Array ( [0] => 17 [id] => 17 [1] => images.jpg [image_url] => images.jpg [2] => img0.jpg [image_url_big] => img0.jpg [3] => great [sub_1] => great [4] => example [sub_2] => example )

Comment: so as shown in the array .. the value didn't come with empty .. so the problem as i said .. the delete query executed before unlink function so when i asked for image_url it will be deleted .. im i right with my thoughts

Comment: This is good to see that result is coming from the database. It helps us a lot to move to next line of code.So now I need your folder structure. and the code which you used when you upload the image.

Comment: No bel, we stored the image_url into the variables $image1 and $image2 so there will not be any kind of effect if the delete query executed before unlink function

Comment: yeah .. about upload script i use a simple script .. it's just upload the img to folder "photo" .. and when anyone want's add the image to database to show in site he has to just put the image name was uploaded [with hes type ] and i use this src="images/photo/<?php echo $rowhair['image_url_big'] ?>" to show images .. hhh it's not professional way but this idea i think for it to avoid that i'm not expert yet in php

Comment: but you upload it any folder right! then I need your folder structure and your upload code.Please provide me to help you

Comment: it's telling me "too long by 100 characters" i will update the answer

Comment: this may help i use the code what "Prased" give me and i given "not existsArray ( [0] => 19 [id] => 19 [1] => images.jpg [image_url] => images.jpg [2] => img0.jpg [image_url_big] => img0.jpg [3] => great [sub_1] => great [4] => example [sub_2] => example )"

Comment: If your upload and delete file are in same folder then use unlink("/images/photo/".$image1); unlink('"/images/photo/".$image2);

Answer (score 0):

check with file exists function like below also enable php errors

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    $imgPath = ''../../images/photo'.$image1';
    if (file_exists($imgPath)) {
         unlink($imgPath);
    } else {
      echo "not exists";
    }
```

Comment: it's good way to know all about the process .. i miss it .. i will try .. a lot thanks

Comment: it show me not existsArray ( [0] => 19 [id] => 19 [1] => images.jpg [image_url] => images.jpg [2] => img0.jpg [image_url_big] => img0.jpg [3] => great [sub_1] => great [4] => example [sub_2] => example )

Comment: yeah i just post an answer before see this comment .. and thank you for notice me that .. a lot lot thanks ... now it's worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

ooh it's worked finally !!!

the all problem .. all time we have spend it was for nothing !

from first time and my first code it was work just fine and every code i have given by you guys it was worked .. but just we all [except "Parasad"]  forgot [/] after "photo" !!!!!!! to be like this

```
unlink('../../images/photo/'.$image1)
```

not like this

```
unlink('../../images/photo'.$image1)
```

really i make you guys work hard to try slove my problem and i take your time

so million huge thanks to all of you specially [WordpressCoder] .. thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

```
if(isset($_GET['delimg'])){

$id= $_GET['delimg'];
$sql = "delete from images_img where id='$id'";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$getname="select * from images_hair";
$res2=mysqli_query($con,$getname);
$image=mysqli_fetch_array($res2);
$image1=$image['image_url'];
$image2=$image['image_url_big'];
unlink('../../images/photo/'.$image1);//check your url
unlink('../../images/photo/'.$image2);//check your url
```

}